# der anderen oder des anderen?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive, grammatical-number

Ich bin etwas verwirrt über die Verwendung des Genitivs. Welcher Satz ist richtig und was ist der Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

1. **Das Wohl der anderen** ist mir wichtiger als mein eigenes.
2. **Die Freiheit des anderen** ist mir wichtig.

Answer (score 2):

Beide sind richtig. Das erste ist Plural (oder theoretisch auch Singular Femininum, ergibt aber nicht wirklich Sinn), das zweite ist Singular Maskulinum (oder evtl. Neutrum).

Ohne Kontext schätze ich, das erste bedeutet "der anderen Menschen" (mehrerer Menschen), das zweite bedeutet "des anderen Menschen" (eines Menschen).

Comment: Der Singular in "Die Freiheit des anderen ist mir wichtig" klingt sehr nach einem repräsentativen Singular (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular) wie in "Liebe deinen Nächsten", d.h. "der Andere" steht fur *alle* anderen.

Comment: @HalvarF ja, natürlich, stimme ich zu; ich habe nur die Grammatik erklärt